does spacing between statements, indentation and comments in code affects its time and space complexity?
I'm trying to understand how code formatting and documentation impacts the performance of a program
Spacing between statements:  having more or fewer blank lines between code statements.
Indentation: The use of tabs or spaces for indentation and whether the level of indentation (nested blocks) has an impact.
I had solved a problem in leetcode using java, every time I submit by making some changes(as mentioned in question) the runtime and memory usage changes.

No, in compiled languages (like java) they don't affect the runtime. How much of a difference are you noticing?

The metrics provided by leetcode arent exactly a good measure. I tried submitting the same piece of code and it can actually give me different results per run. You need to actually profile and measure it yourself

And, more generally, they don't affect time and space complexity because those are theoretical models of how the program will perform and are not directly tied to run time or memory occupation. Two algorhithms that have a O(n) time complexity can have, say, a 10x difference in actual clock time if n is big enough

It does not affect the performance, it affects readability. Java compiled, the same source code will result in the same byte code, regardless of the code style used. And the statistics of leetcode and other such sites are generally unreliable.

Omitting all optional whitespace might make the compilation quicker (by a miniscule amount). Actual code execution time? No effect whatsoever. It's not semantically meaningful and has no presence in byte code.

No, when it's "compiled" the comments an whitespace are not included in the result.

if the code is interpreted - no idea how leetcode works - it can have some minor impact at execution time, but it sure will not change time nor space complexity (e.g. the code will not loop more often or use more space, depending on N() Maybe  you can try, just for testing, to re-submit the same code?

It affects performance in the sense that it affects how well the next programmer reading your code performs. Which is much more important than run time and memory usage.

Java is a compiled language. When it is compiled, all spacing, indenting and comments are discarded. Only code is converted to executable format.
The issue you are seeing is probably you don't control the execution environment and there may be competing processes. Or it may be that the site uses an interpreter. Even with an interpreter the time parsing those parts is likely small or irrelevant. For sure it doesn't impact the complexity of an algorithm.
As other mentioned in the comments, you should perform your own testing in a controlled environment to get consistent results.
